# Add and delete elements onClick in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React JS and I am trying to create new groups and rows onClick of a button. So I have an array named `groups` which gives me the Parent component and then another array named `rows` which loops and gives the Row component. I have 2 methods, `addRow` and `addGroup` to add a new Parent component and row component dynamically. But everytime I add or delete a row, it seems to add and delete from all the groups. How can I keep every group and row separate from each other?

This is what my App.js file looks like:-

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Parent from './Parent.js'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    rows: [
      {id:0,value: 'row1', options:[1,2,3,4,5] }
    ],
    groups : [
      { id:0, title: 'New Group' }
    ],
  }

  updateValue = (e, idx) => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx].value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      rows,
    });
  }

  addNewGroup = () => {
    const groups = [...this.state.groups, { id:this.state.groups.length, title: 'New Group'}]
    this.setState({
      groups
    })
  }

  addRow = () => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows, {id: this.state.rows.length ,value:'',options: []}];
    this.setState({
      rows,
    });
  }

  deleteRow = (item) => {
    let filtered = this.state.rows.filter(row => row.id !== item.id);
    this.setState ({
      rows: filtered
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className = "App">
      {
        this.state.groups.map ( (group,idx) => {
          return (
            <Parent
            key = {idx}
            title = {group.title }
            rows = { this.state.rows }
            deleteRow = {this.deleteRow.bind(this) }/>
          )
        })
      }
      <button onClick = {this.addRow}> Add </button>
      <button onClick = {this.addNewGroup }>Add Group  </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

This is what my parent component looks like:-

```js
import React from 'react'
import Row from './Row.js'

const Parent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
    <h4>{ props.title }</h4>
    {
      props.rows.map( (row,idx) => {
        return (
          <Row
          key = {idx}
          index = {idx}
          value = { row.value }
          options = { row.options }
          delete = { () => { props.deleteRow(row) } }/>
        )
      })
    }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Parent;
```

This is my Row component:-

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Row.css'

const Row = ( props) => {
  let options = props.options.map(opt => <option key={opt}>{opt}</option>);

  return (
    <div>
    <input></input>
    <select>
    {options}
    </select>
    <button onClick = { () => { props.delete(props.index); } } > Delete </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Row
```

So basically addGroup should give me a new group and I should be able to add and delete rows individually without affecting the rows in the other group. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked what you had a bit.  The gist of it is that each group owns an array of rows, they aren't separate like you have in your example.  When you want to modify a group, pass in its id, when you want to modify a row, pass in its group's id and it's (row) id.  In a perfect world, you would generate UUIDs for each of these, so you would only have to pass in the row's id to update/delete it.  The cool thing about React is that the component structure should end up mirroring the data structure.  `<App>` -> many `<Group>`s -> each Group has many `<Row>`s.

```js
const { Component } = React;
const options = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    groups : [
      { id: 0, title: 'New Group', rows: [{ id: 0,value: 'row1', options }] }
    ],
  }

  // this isn't hooked up to anything yet
  updateValue = (e, rowId, groupId) => {
    let groups = [...this.state.groups];

    groups = groups.map(group => {
      if (group.id === groupId) {
        group.rows = group.rows.map(row => {
          if (row.id === rowId) {
            row.value = e.target.value;
          }

          return row
        })
      }

      return group;
    });

    this.setState({ groups });
   }

   addNewGroup = () => {
    const groups = [...this.state.groups, { id:this.state.groups.length, title: 'New Group', rows: [] }]
    this.setState({ groups });
  }
  
  removeGroup = (groupId) => {
    const groups = this.state.groups.filter(group => group.id !== groupId);
    
    this.setState({ groups });
  }

  addRow = (groupId) => {
    let groups = [...this.state.groups];

    groups = groups.map(group => {
      if (group.id === groupId) {
        const id = group.rows.length;
        group.rows.push({ id, value: `row${id}`, options })
      }

      return group;
    });

      this.setState({ groups });
   };

  deleteRow = (rowId, groupId) => {
    let groups = [...this.state.groups];

    groups = groups.map(group => {
    console.log(group, rowId)
      if (group.id === groupId) {
        group.rows = group.rows.filter(row => row.id !== rowId)
      }

      return group;
    });

    this.setState ({ groups });
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div className = "App">
     {this.state.groups.map ( (group, idx) => (
       <div>
          <Parent
            key={idx}
             title={group.title}
             group={group}
             removeGroup={this.removeGroup.bind(this)}
           />
           <button onClick = {() => this.addRow(group.id)}> Add Row </button>
           <button onClick = {() => this.removeGroup(group.id)}> Remove Group </button>
       </div>
      ))}
      
      <button onClick = {this.addNewGroup }>Add Group  </button>
   </div>
    )
  }
}

const Parent = (props) => {
  return (
     <div>
       <h4>{ props.title }</h4>
       {props.group.rows.map((row, idx) => (
           <Row
             key={idx}
             index={idx}
             value={ row.value }
             options={ row.options }
             delete={() => { props.deleteRow(row.id, props.group.id) }}
           />
         ))
       }
     </div>
    )
}

const Row = ( props) => {
  let options = props.options.map(opt => <option key={opt}>{opt}</option>);

  return (
     <div>
      <input></input>
      <select>
          {options}
      </select>
      <button onClick={props.delete}> Delete </button>
     </div>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You sir are awesome!!! Thank you so much!!! Also accepted this as an answer. :)

Comment: Haha sure.  I didn't do a full refactor but hopefully that's enough to get you set in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, could you help me with the logic if i want to delete an entire group as well?

Comment: Sure! Just create a function in the parent that takes a `groupId` and does something like `this.setState({ groups: this.state.groups.filter(group => group.id !== groupId) })`.  Then pass that function to each `Parent` and pass the `groupId` when you call that function `onClick={() => props.deleteGroup(group.id) }`

Comment: okay i was on the right track lol. Again, thank you so much :D

Comment: I am sorry i am a little late in finding this but the deletRow function seems to be deleting last row first irrespective of whichever one i delete.

Comment: So even if i click on the second delete, it still deletes the last one first.

Comment: Not sure what you were trying to do, but check my edits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206890/discussion-between-treehuggerrick-and-larz).